# Prettier not working on VScode tried everything from stackoverflow still nothing happened?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, prettier

Prettier not working on VSCode

I have been using prettier for java on vs code from very long everything was working smoothly till yesterday and suddenly prettier stopped working for java.

I have tried every available resource on Youtube and Stack Overflow still didn't solve my issue, please help.

I tried from changing default formatter and format on save to `settings.json` still now working showing error - `FormattingExtension 'Prettier - Code formatter' is configured as formatter but it cannot format 'Java'-files`

Answer (score 1):

Normally this happens when you have another extension overlapping the prettier settings. Disabling other extensions normally solves the problem. Reinstalling visual studio can be your best option, but you have to remove all remaining settings, or it will just be the same.

You can always install directly in terminal using: https://prettier.io/docs/en/install.html

Confirm on extensions that prettier is enabled. Update Visual Studio and Windows.